# How to I have a <span> within a <li> align to the right side of the <li>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a span of the class 'label' [from the bootstrap framework](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges).  I have this label nested within a `<li>` and I would like it to align right of the rest of the content in the `<li>`.

Before I try to modify the css my li's look like this (the orange 'new item' is the label):[image: no css]

If I try `float: right` the label moves to the right, but is at the upper right corner of the `<li>` as seen here:[image: float right]

You can also see the new item label gets pushed to the next line in one situation - I think that is an unrelated problem.

Any tips on how to get my 'new item' span to move to the right of my `<li>` ?  Here is a link to a page I have hosted for demonstration purposes:  [a](http://frozen-stream-7233.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: use `class= "pull-right"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving class `label` margin seems to help:

```
span.label {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Elegant - I used `margin-top: 10px;` with the bootstrap class `pull-right`

Comment: You may want to correct the typo in 'spant.label' for future reference -- I cannot make such a minor edit to your post.

Comment: Elegant, but doesn't fix his double label problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
<li class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">Description of item 1</div>
  <span class="offset1 span2 label pull-right">new item</span>
</li>
<li class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">Description of item 2</div>
  <span class="offset1 span2 label pull-right">new item</span>
</li>
```

---

```
<li class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">Description of item 1</div>
  <div class="offset1 span2 btn btn-large">new item</div>
</li>
<li class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">Description of item 2</div>
  <div class="offset1 span2 btn btn-large">new item</div>
</li>
```

---

```
<li class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">Description of item 1</div>
  <span class="offset1 span2 label">new item</span>
</li>
<li class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">Description of item 2</div>
  <span class="offset1 span2 label">new item</span>
</li>
```

Comment: This still bumps the label up to the 'top right' instead of just sliding it right as seen in the second picture above.

Comment: . . .  Well that exploded rapidly.  I'm not sure what to do when you provide so many different edits so rapidly.  None of these options does exactly what I need them to do either - they all seem to 'blow up' my label too.  I appreciate the effort as I did come here for answers - but try less of a 'shot-gun' approach next time?

Comment: Sure, actually I am trying those methods myself, just waiting for the best one

Answer (score 1):

try with position relative

```
span.label{
float: right;
position:relative;
top:5px;
}
```

ex. http://prntscr.com/rbzpp

Answer (score 0):

This fixed all your problems with just css.

```
.label-warning, .badge-warning {
    background-color: #f89406;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
.product_summary {
    clear: both;
}
.product_summary img {
    float: left;
}
.name, .price {
    float: left;
    line-height: 37px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin for placing the button in middle from top.Another you can use the position for the same like `position:absolute; right:0; top:45%`.This code is even work better when the  size(height) of image increases.